# Confused about representation of an inertial frame by a one-form

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, vectors, tensor-calculus, definition

I'm self-studying general relativity and I'm using Schutz's text.  A lot is starting to click but some things are pretty confusing, especially this part which seems pretty important.

There's a Section 3.3 talking about notation for derivatives in which is given:
$x^\alpha_{,\beta}\equiv \delta^\beta_\alpha$.  Fine so far.  Then by comparison with an earlier equation given we have this implying:  $$\tilde{\mathrm{d}}x^\alpha := \tilde{\omega}^\alpha.\tag{3.20}$$

My understanding is that $\tilde{\omega}$ represents the one-form basis.  So, is $\tilde{\mathrm{d}}x^\alpha$ just notation defining now the $\alpha$-th basis of the one-form?  Why the new notation (if I'm even right about that).

Then he says we can use this to write, for any function $f$:
$
\tilde{\mathrm{d}}f = {\partial f \over\partial x^\alpha}\tilde{\mathrm{d}}x^\alpha.
$

warning not to confuse $\tilde{\mathrm{d}}f$ with a differential, as it's a tensor.  Unfortunately, I'm very confused by this.  Is this because $f$ is a function (one-form) which acts on $\tilde{\mathrm{d}}x^\alpha$?  What really is the meaning of $\tilde{\mathrm{d}}f$?

This comes up again in the next chapter when introducing 4-vectors with special fluids.  It's shown that an inertial frame can be represented by a one-form, e.g.
$
E = \langle\tilde{\mathrm{d}}t, \vec{p}\rangle = p^0
$
This is the inner product of $\tilde{\mathrm{d}}t$ and $\vec{p}$ correct?  Again though, what is the meaning of $\tilde{\mathrm{d}}t$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the reader is probably thinking: *What's with all the tildes?* Well, Schutz in Section 3.3 *adopts the notation that $\raise.8ex\tilde{}$ above a symbol denotes a one-form, just as $\vec{}$ above a symbol denotes a vector.*

OP asks:

> What really is the meaning of $\tilde{\mathrm{d}}f$?

The one-form/co-vector $\tilde{\mathrm{d}}f$ acts on vectors $\vec{A}~=~A^{\mu}e_{\mu}$, which are identified with first order differential operators $\vec{A}~=~A^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}$, which in turn act on functions $f$, so  $$\langle \tilde{\mathrm{d}}f, \vec{A}\rangle~:=~\vec{A}[f]~=~A^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}f.$$